# list object has no attribute model in drf

Tags: django, exception, django-rest-framework

I am trying to return a list(created using queryset) from the overriden **get_queryset()** method. I can't return queryset directly as i have to change the columns names returned in the queryset.

```
def get_queryset(self):
    project_id=self.request.query_params.get('projectid')


    labelled_img= LabelledImage.objects.filter(project_id=project_id).values('label_id')

    queryset=ArtialClass.objects.filter(labels__label_id__in=labelled_img).values_list('class_name').annotate(total=Count('class_id')).order_by('class_name')
    pagination.PageNumberPagination.page_size = 1000

    return [{'class_name':i[0],'total':i[1]} for i in queryset]
```

Serializers.py

```
class ClassificationSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    class_name=serializers.CharField(max_length=20)
    total = serializers.IntegerField()
```

In normal scenario, the code is working fine. But when i am trying to append Filter class

```
filter_backends = (filters.DjangoFilterBackend,)
filterset_class = ListClassFilter
```

I am getting the following error:

```
  model = queryset.model
  AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'model'
```

Traceback

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\shubham.kumar30\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda2\envs\artial\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\shubham.kumar30\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda2\envs\artial\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Users\shubham.kumar30\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda2\envs\artial\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\shubham.kumar30\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda2\envs\artial\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\shubham.kumar30\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda2\envs\artial\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\viewsets.py", line 114, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\shubham.kumar30\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda2\envs\artial\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 505, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "C:\Users\shubham.kumar30\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda2\envs\artial\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 465, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "C:\Users\shubham.kumar30\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda2\envs\artial\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 476, in raise_uncaught_exception
    raise exc
  File "C:\Users\shubham.kumar30\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda2\envs\artial\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 502, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\shubham.kumar30\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda2\envs\artial\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\mixins.py", line 38, in list
    queryset = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset())
  File "C:\Users\shubham.kumar30\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda2\envs\artial\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\generics.py", line 150, in filter_queryset
    queryset = backend().filter_queryset(self.request, queryset, self)
  File "C:\Users\shubham.kumar30\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda2\envs\artial\lib\site-packages\django_filters\rest_framework\backends.py", line 90, in filter_queryset
    filterset = self.get_filterset(request, queryset, view)
  File "C:\Users\shubham.kumar30\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda2\envs\artial\lib\site-packages\django_filters\rest_framework\backends.py", line 36, in get_filterset
    return filterset_class(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\shubham.kumar30\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda2\envs\artial\lib\site-packages\django_filters\filterset.py", line 187, in __init__
    model = queryset.model
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'model'
[02/Mar/2020 15:01:00] "GET /artial/proj2/classification/ HTTP/1.1" 500 19919
```

Answer (score 0):

Filter backend is expecting you to return a queryset. You are returning a list. Modify your code like this

```
def get_queryset(self):
    project_id=self.request.query_params.get('projectid')

    labelled_img= LabelledImage.objects.filter(project_id=project_id).values('label_id')

    queryset=ArtialClass.objects.filter(labels__label_id__in=labelled_img).annotate(total=Count('class_id')).order_by('class_name')

    pagination.PageNumberPagination.page_size = 1000

    return queryset
```

Comment: AttributeError: Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `class_name` on serializer `ClassificationSerializer`.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `tuple` instance.
Original exception text was: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'class_name'.

Comment: @Muhamad Hassan I have added serializer class

Comment: Remove `.values('class_name', 'total')` part from your code in `get_queryset` method. Updated my code.

Comment: I need those attributes only, so removing them won't help.

Comment: Your serializer will return only those attribute of your queryset that you have declared in your serializer. You are getting this error because with `values`, you get list of dictionary and in dictionary,you cannot access your attribute like `object.attribute_name` which give `AttributeError`.